# Compiling a given latex file

Tags: errors, compiling

I'm trying to compile BPI.tex [here](http://www.math.purdue.edu/~hrubin/JeanRubin/Papers/) because, as you can see, the given compiled file has the lower end of each page cut off. The problem is: I get lots of "undefined control sequence" errors but if I cut the paragraph containing the error, delete aux and log files, quit TexShop and then recompile, I get the same error on the same line even if the line is then blank (since I cut it out).

What is going on here? Is TexShop broken? Why does editing the file not have any effect? And how can I compile this file?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question instead of linking to code hosted elsewhere.

Comment: @Jubobs The file I'm trying to compile is really long. What should I do? Copy paste the beginning and the end of it?

Comment: Nevermind. egreg already answered your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The file is meant to be compiled with `amstex` rather than LaTeX. Just move the first line after the second one

```
\input amstex
\undefine\eth
\documentstyle{amsppt}
\NoBlackBoxes
<...>
```

and use "Plain TeX" as the typesetting engine from the drop down menu

[image]

Comment: You are a lifesaver! It's like magic! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MattN. Ages ago I was using `amstex` myself. ;-)